# If the Lab has two PIs, Should I send my cold email to both of them?

Tags: graduate-school

I am interested in joining a lab that has two principal investigators, Should I CC the other person in the first cold email I am sending?

Ps, their family name is the same, so the mail would still be tailored to both of them.

Comment: "Ps, their family name is the same, so the mail would still be tailored to both of them." This is a strange argument to make. In any case, you should not send an email where it's not clear whether the intended recipient is Prof. A. Smith, Prof. B. Smith, or both.